# Video overlapping on Ipad

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

I have added the video in background named "#supersize-background" with fixed position.
and header is absolute on the video.

While video is playing I am unable to click on header navigation. you can check on this link http://redzone.wordpressprojects.com/

Comment: No iPad to debug with here, but is the plugin you're using to display the video on an iPad possibly overlaying the navigation with a higher z-index?

Comment: yes the z-index of video is lower than the video

Comment: if I resize the screen on my mac with Chrome then resize the browser window to an iPad size, then many of the links on the right, such as "Featured" go off the screen.  Is off the screen the issue?